# how can i build StackUpEffect in react with tailwind

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to implement the card stacking on the top when scrolling like the following site.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oPAULoBJ74&list=WL&index=1&t=1s
I want to implement it with React and Tailwind. I've tried it many times by myself and I'm having a hard time since I just started coding.

I tried to solve it using useEffect, but it failed.
I don't know if I can solve it simply by using sticky yet.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul id="cards">
        <li class="card" id="card1">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Card 1</h2>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="card" id="card2">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Card 2</h2>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="card" id="card3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Card 3</h2>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="card" id="card4">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Card 4</h2>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
body {
  background-color: #2e3537;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --cards: 4;
  --cardHeight: 87vh;
  --cardTopPadding: 1.5em;
  --cardMargin: 4vw;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#cards {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--cards), var(--cardHeight));
  gap: var(--cardMargin);
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--cards) * var(--cardTopPadding));
  margin-bottom: var(--cardMargin);
}

#card1 {
  --index: 1;
}
#card2 {
  --index: 2;
}
#card3 {
  --index: 3;
}
#card4 {
  --index: 4;
}

.card {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: calc(var(--index) * var(--cardTopPadding));
}

#card1 .card-body {
  background-color: #52b2cf;
}
#card2 .card-body {
  /* background-color: #7EC4CF; */
  background-color: #e5a36f;
}
#card3 .card-body {
  background-color: #9cadce;
}
#card4 .card-body {
  background-color: #d4afb9;
}

.card-body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: var(--cardHeight);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

I would like to implement the attached html,css code as react,tailwind!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.